# remove natural indent of inner list

Tags: enumitem

I have a list of lists.  How do I remove the indent of the inner list so that Inner List 1, 2, and 3 align with Main List 1.  In other words, what is the default item indent for each level?

```
\item[] Main List 1
\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*,labelindent=0pt]
\item[] Inner List 1
\item[] Inner List 2
\item[] Inner List 3
```

I think I have to change the leftmargin parameter, but I just don't know by how much.  It looks like leftmargin=10pt works, but I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to set `leftmargin` to 0pt.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[] Main List 1
\item[] Main List 2
\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=0pt,labelindent=0pt]
\item[] Inner List 1
\item[] Inner List 2
\item[] Inner List 3
\end{itemize}
\item[] Main List 3
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ok, thanks.  I get it.  And to help others, if you add the parameter itemindent, you have to compensate by that same amount:  [nosep,leftmargin=1em,labelindent=0pt,itemindent=-1em]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the different levels of indentation separately using `\setlist[itemize,<level>]{..}` from enumitem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\setlist[itemize,2]{leftmargin=0pt}

\noindent normal text
\begin{itemize}
\item[] Main List 1
\begin{itemize}[nosep,labelindent=0pt]
\item[] Inner List 1
\item[] Inner List 2
\item[] Inner List 3
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Playing with the `wide` key`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[47]
\begin{itemize}[label={}]
\item Main List 1
\item Main List 2. Some text at the upper level. Some more text at the upper level. Still some more text.
\begin{itemize}[label={}, nosep, wide=0pt, itemindent = 0pt]
\item Inner List 1. Some text at the lower level. Some more text at the lower level. Still some more text. S
\item Inner List 2
\item Inner List 3
\end{itemize}
\item Main List 3
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]